# firefox uploadify button disappears

Tags: firefox, uploadify

I'm using uploadify with jQuery ui tabs on an ASP.NET 3.5 page. All works fine with Chrome; when I swap tabs the uploadiify button flashes, but is there as the tab slides-in.

With Firefox (17.0.1) the tab slides in & the uploadify button is shown, it flashes off & is not shown again. I can force it to show by doing a partial page post back from an ASP: button. If I simulate the ASP: button click with jQuery it doesn't load the uploadify button.

I think it may be some kind of timing issue so I've put the uploadify() function in a settimeout() but that hasn't solved it. I thought this because if I fire an alert after the tab slides-in & the uploadify is 'binding' the uploadify button is shown.

I've tried the uploadify demo page & that's OK so it's not a problem with Firefox flash version.

Any ideas?

This is my uploadify 'binding' function - it works OK with Chrome so I figure all the paths are good. The onSWFReady was an attempt to sort this problem - no good.

```
    function InitialiseNewUploadifyControl() {

        var prefix = "Attachment_";
        var auth = "<% = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] == null ? string.Empty : Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value %>";
        var ASPSESSID = "<%= Session.SessionID %>";
        var jobId = $(".job-Id").text();
        
        if ($('#fileInputNewUploader').length < 1) {
            console.log("fileInputNewUploader : " + $('#fileInputNewUploader').length.toString());
            var _log = $('#fileInputNew').uploadify({
                'uploader': '/Scripts/Uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'script': 'Handlers/Upload.ashx',
                'scriptData': { 'prefix': prefix, 'ASPSESSID': ASPSESSID, 'AUTHID': auth, 'JobId': jobId,
                    "UploadImmediate": false
                },
                'cancelImg': 'Scripts/Uploadify/cancel.png',
                'auto': true,
                'multi': true,
                'fileDesc': 'All Files',
                'fileExt': '*.*',
                'queueSizeLimit': 10,
                'sizeLimit': 4000000,
                'buttonText': 'Upload Files',
                'folder': '/Uploads',
                'removeCompleted': false,
                'onComplete': function (event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
                    $("<%= ui_lblHiddenResizeControl.ClientID %>").text("false");
                    if (response == "0") {
                        alert('Sorry, the file type that was just uploaded is not allowed.');
                        jQuery('#fileInputNew').uploadifyCancel(ID);
                    } else {
                        $("#<%= ui_lblHiddenResizeControl.ClientID %>").text("true");
                        //$(".hidden-row-click").click();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                /*
                , 'onSWFReady': function () {
                    //$("#fileInputNewUploader").parent().css({ "visability": "visible", "background-color": "Gray" });
                    HideTopLoader();
                    console.log("onSWFReady_fileInputNewUploader : " + $('#fileInputNewUploader').length.toString());
                    if ($('.FFFix-hidden-button-click').val() === "unclicked") {
                        $('.FFFix-hidden-button-click').click();
                        console.log("onSWFReady_fileInputNewUploader click");
                    }
                }
                */
            });
            console.log('%o', _log);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demos work fine so the flash player is OK. I moved to binding code to the jquery ui Tabs function/method; check which tab is selected & bind if it's the 1 I'mm after, this fixed things.. no setTimeout required.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue  with FireFox, you needs to update/install Adobe Flash player for FireFox

Comment: The demos work fine so the flash player is OK. I moved to binding code to the jquery ui Tabs function/method; check which tab is selected & bind if it's the 1 I'mm after, this fixed things.. no setTimeout required.